# How to double melee attack damage within same tick as projectile strike

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

In many Java Edition servers, there are plugins in which you can deal double damage by hitting someone with a projectile such as a snowball or a fishing rod and then your sword within a given time period.

How can I make projectiles work the same way in Bedrock Edition using commands or some other way?

Comment: Does the double damaged only apply after hitting someone with the projectile?

Comment: Yes, if the projectile and weapon hit within the same damage tick it does double damage

Comment: Should the throwing player have their attack doubled or the defending player have their defense halved?

Comment: The attack is doubled